Ошибка компиляции проекта Qt после добавления файла ресурсы
такая проблема:
В любом проекте qmake, при добавлении в него файла '*.qrc', дальнейшая компиляция выдает ошибку в файле "Makefile.Debug".
...\Makefile.Debug:105: ошибка: multiple target patterns.  Stop.
debug/qrc_bjl.cpp: ../../bjl.qrc \
        ../../../../Qt/6.7.2/mingw_64/bin/rcc.exe \
        вЂ™ТђР„РіР№В Рї\ Р„В®В¤В®СћВ Рї\ Р±РІР°В В­РЃР¶В :\ 1251
    D:\Qt\6.7.2\mingw_64\bin\rcc.exe -name bjl --no-zstd ..\..\bjl.qrc -o debug\qrc_bjl.cpp


Вот фрагмент куда указывает компилятор.
Ошибка скорее всего связана с битой кодировкой , но я не знаю почему она побилась и как это исправить на корню.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72194032/4711135
